# How to display a star rating widget in an ExtJS list itemTpl?

Tags: javascript, extjs4, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm working on a Sencha Touch 2 application and using the star rating widget from http://podlipensky.com/post/2012/03/20/Sencha-Touch-2-ExtuxtouchRating.aspx

I would like to show the rating for each item within a list that is configured like this:

```
Ext.define('Schneehoehen.view.LoipenUebersicht', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype: 'loipenuebersicht',

config: {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'list',
        title: 'Loipen Übersicht',
        itemTpl: '{label}', // I would like to show the widget next to the label
        onItemDisclosure: true,

        store: Ext.create('Schneehoehen.store.LoipenUebersichtStore')
    }]
}
})
```

Now I'm wondering how to include my star rating widget within the itemTpl.

The widget is displayed within a form of another view using the following code:

```
new Ext.ux.touch.Rating({
   itemsCount: 5, 
   label: 'Image less', 
   cls: 'x-imageless-rating', 
   itemCls: 'x-imageless-star', 
   itemHoverCls: 'x-imageless-hover'
})
```

Thanks in advance!
Johannes

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is how to get XTypes or other components inside a list's itemTpl template. I don't know of a direct method but even if you do manage to write your own using the template methods its very tough to have them inside the list items. Besides why have so many components hog up dom.

If you can slightly modify your approach here, there is this beautiful plugin on swarm online that could probably help you with this issue. http://www.swarmonline.com/2011/03/ext-ux-touch-listoptions-demo/

This plugin adds twitter app style menu on swipe of a list row. You can add a star rating in this area. I remember I had used it in a POC and had added Sencha buttons to the menu that shows up.
I am not sure if they have updated their code to be compatible with Sencha Touch 2 but if you look at the source closely there's not much in there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are keen to use sencha components there then the most simple way is to use component dataview. See http://www.sencha.com/blog/dive-into-dataview-with-sencha-touch-2-beta-2/ for more details.